# Regex to replace "../" into a url

Tags: regex

i want to replace file path from image with an url.

Current Situation:
Ive got `<img src="` with the following possibilities:

```
../../..//assets/test/test/test.png
../../../assets/test/test/test.png
../..//assets/test/test/test.png
../../assets/test/test/test.png
..//assets/test/test/test.png
../assets/test/test/test.png
/assets/test/test/test.png
assets/test/test/test.png
```

I want to replace every `../` or `..//` + `assets/` with a url `https://example.com/`
I've tried to find a working regex, which matches to everything before `assets/`

I am using this regex to find/replace with gulp

UPDATE:

i was able to match everything until `assets/` but i need it included:

```
/.+?(?=assets\/)/gm
```

See: https://regex101.com/r/VqQS2L/1/

Comment: did you mean `.*?(?=assets\/)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: `Regex.Replace("(.|\/)*assets\/" , "https://example.com");`. Check this [here](https://regex101.com/r/aP0qH2/324)

Answer (score 0):

```
.*?assets\/
```

it is the solution